# Scheduled Task optimisation access, excel and sharepoint "called"

Tags: excel, ms-access, sharepoint, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have searched quite extensively and cannot find the answers that I am looking for, so I wondered if you could help me out.

I have a particular client that uses a rather archaic setup to update some files with information.

They:

1. Need a drive mapping (this is available through a UNC path and I believe links to spreadsheets are relative not hardcoded fixed paths using the drive letter)
2. call a *.mdb file and this obviously contains some executable code
3. The code launches Excel and queries spreadsheets
4. The code also queries Sharepoint (this also requires a login with a different password).
5. Eventually reports are updated for the client.

Now this all runs from an account, that needs to be logged in to the console of a Windows server to enable it to run via a scheduled task. Obviously at the time if you were to be shadowing that console session you would see the spreadsheets launching and the whole process executing.

I am not in a position to deconstruct the code to bring this up to date.

I would however like to avoid having to have an account logged in to perform this action, would prefer it to remain an automated task. I have searched for methods to do this with powershell and vb and quite frankly I'm looking for suggestions on how best to go about this or even if its possible without wasting hundreds of man hours before realising this is the case.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: I would recommend reading [Considerations for server-side automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757). This type of thing isn't supported by Microsoft, but they do give guidance on potential problems and alternatives to consider.

Answer (score 0):

The Office products may be automated via their Interop model. Documentation of the model as well as the basic principles are available on the MSDN:
[Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865816.aspx), [Primary Interop Assembly References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190883%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Creating a new instance of Excel from PowerShell is really simple and is done as such:

```
    $Excel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

Unfortunately I never tried to run Excel (or any other Office tool) as a scheduled task. You will have to try that for yourself.